# How to determine which radio button was selected in C# ASP.NET CORE MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, radio-button

I am wanting to check to see which radio button was selected from my `Index.cshtml` file and from there I would like to use a switch statement to set attributes to its object. I was reading up on how to do this but majority of them were for groups in a windows form but that would not apply to me since I am using a asp.net core 5.0 web mvc project.

In my `Index.cshmtl` I have the following:

```
....
<form action="@Url.Action("SecIndex", "Second")">

    <input type="radio" value="1" /><label>Valid</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" /><label>Wrong</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" /><label>InValid</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Address Validation" />

</form>
```

then in my `HomeController`, I have the following method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ValidateAddress()
        {
            // if radio button was checked, perform the following var request.


            var check = ""; // this should be able to grab the label of the button that was selected

            switch (check)
            {
                case "Valid":
                   var request = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 1,
                        Address = "2018 Main St New York City, NY, 10001"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Wrong":
                    var req = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 2,
                        Address = "91 Apple City Galveston, TX, 77550"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Invalid":
                    var addressRequest = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 3,
                        Address = "00000 Tree Ln, Miami FL 91041"
                    };
                    break;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to allow variable `check` to perform a check to see which radio button was selected since this is a asp.net core 5.0 web mvc project and not a windows form. Is there a way to do this in this type of project?

---

**UPDATE:**

So I realized that I wanted to have the Value as it was before with numbers. So implementing the suggestion, I needed to still redirect the user to the method `SecIndex` in my `Second` controller. However, I still needed to grab the value of radio button that was selected. So I attempted to do `return RedirectToAction("SecIndex");` but when I ran the program and hit the button to validate it gave me:

> This page isn't working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
> HTTP ERROR 405

Did I do something incorrectly? the URI shows up as `https://localhost:5443/Home/ValidateAddress?Status=1`. Not I did select the first option, which should give me Status as 1. Not sure why it is returning that though.

Inside of my `HomeController`:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ValidateAddress(string validate)
        {
            // if radio button was checked, perform the following var request.

            switch (validate)
            {
                case "Valid":
                   var request = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 1,
                        Address = "2018 Main St New York City, NY, 10001"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Wrong":
                    var req = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 2,
                        Address = "91 Apple City Galveston, TX, 77550"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Invalid":
                    var addressRequest = new AddressRequest
                    {
                        StatusCode = 3,
                        Address = "00000 Tree Ln, Miami FL 91041"
                    };
                    break;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("SecIndex");
        }

    }
```

`Home View... index.cshtml`:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ValidateAddress", "Home")">

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="Status"/><label>Valid</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="Status"/><label>Wrong</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="Status"/><label>InValid</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Address Validation" />

</form>
```

Comment: SecIndex action covered by [HttpPost] filter?

Comment: The first SecIndex does not have a [HttpPost] filter, but the second one does. I will share in post. Please see updated post @MeysamAsadi

Comment: Is it possible to enter the SecIndex action code?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean exactly by that?

Comment: Oh, well if you do <form action="@Url.Action("SecIndex", "Second")"> instead of "ValidateAddress, Second" it will redirect me to the SecIndex, then after typing the info into the textbox it will enter the HttpPost SecIndex method. Its just if I do that @Url.Action with SecIndex, how would I be able to call the AddressValidate method inside of my homecontroller

Comment: You are doing wrong. The name you choose for the radiobutton must be equal to the action input parameters. There is a problem with your question code and I entered it in response.

Comment: Copy the answer code exactly.

Comment: Yes, so I realized that I did not want to change the `value` from 1,2,3 to the name of the label `Valid, wrong, invalid` so I used what you said but kept the value as 1,2,3. Since I am using `1,2,3` I would need to change the switch cases from `valid` to case "1" correct?

Comment: You have used "Valid" in the case, ie the input value must be a string. It works if you copy my answer code and pay attention to details and do not change the names in the answer I entered.

Comment: I copied the code and still am getting the same results. However, the index.cshtml I did not use "action="@Url.Action("ValidateAddress", "Second")" since "ValidateAddress" is inside of my Home controller not my Second Controller

Comment: I edited the view code. please check it .

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I saw that the Index.cshtml now had post for its action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the radio buttons a common name and assign the label text to the value of the radio buttons.

change `Index.cshmtl` to :

```
<form method="post" action="/DemSecondo/ValidateAddress">
    <input type="radio" value="Valid" name="myRadio" /><label>Valid</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="myRadio" /><label>Wrong</label>
    <input type="radio" value="InValid" name="myRadio" /><label>InValid</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Address Validation" />
</form>
```

and change `ValidateAddress` action to :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ValidateAddress(string myRadio)
{
    switch (myRadio)
    {
        case "Valid":
          var request = new AddressRequest
          {
              StatusCode = 1,
              Address = "2018 Main St New York City, NY, 10001"
          };
          break;
        case "Wrong":
          var req = new AddressRequest
          {
              StatusCode = 2,
              Address = "91 Apple City Galveston, TX, 77550"
          };
          break;
        case "Invalid":
          var addressRequest = new AddressRequest
          {
              StatusCode = 3,
              Address = "00000 Tree Ln, Miami FL 91041"
          };
          break;
     }

     return RedirectToAction("SecIndex");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the `Index.cshtml`, if I am wanting to redirect to the method `SecIndex` which gives me a different view but still be able to grab the value of `myRadio` how would I go about doing this?

Comment: My ValidateAddress is inside of my HomeController, I wanted to redirect to the method `SecIndex` inside of my other controller named `Second`

Comment: use <form action="@Url.Action("SecIndex", "Second")">

Comment: Please see my updated post under "Updated" section